# MOD_WSGI Apache2 You don't have permission to access this resource

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, digital-ocean

I am working on deploying a Django project with apache2 and MOD_WSGI. When I run the server, I am unable to access the website and I get the error on the site,

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at testnexusstudy.com Port 8081
```

[image]
I have set up everything I think I need like the conf file,

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html


ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

Alias /static /root/StudBud1/static
<Directory /root/StudBud1/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /media /root/StudBud1/media
<Directory /root/StudBud1/media>
    Require all granted
</Directory>


<Directory /root/StudBud1/StudBud1>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /root/StudBud1/StudBud1/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess StudBud1 python-path=/root/StudBud1
WSGIProcessGroup StudBud1


</VirtualHost>
```

I have given all the permissions I thought were required for apache and here is my ls -la

```
drwxrwxr-x 12 root www-data  4096 Apr  5 19:36 StudBud1
-rw-rw-r--  1 root www-data 204800 Apr  5 19:36 db.sqlite3
```

Hopefully, some of you have experience with this type of error.

Comment: The permissions don't look quite right, shouldn't they be owned by `www-data`? `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use or give root access to your web server for security reasons.

I would create a user that only has access to the www-data group, make sure apache is also in that group.

Some of these commands come from the Fedora distro, so they may be a little different from Debian.

```
$ adduser deploy
$ vim /etc/group
```

In /etc/group:

```
www-data:x:1003:apache,deploy
```

/location/to/vhosts/website.conf (extraneous settings removed for clarity)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    Alias /static/ /srv/vhosts/mywebsite/static/
    Alias /media/ /srv/vhosts/mywebsite/media/
    Alias /robots.txt /srv/vhosts/robots.txt

    <Directory /srv/vhosts/mywebsite/path/to/django/configs>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /srv/vhosts/mywebsite/static>
      Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /srv/vhosts/mywebsite/media>
      Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Location "/robots.txt">
      SetHandler None
      Require all granted
    </Location>

    WSGIDaemonProcess mywebsite python-home=/srv/vhosts/mywebsite/.venv python-path=/srv/vhosts/mywebsite/
    WSGIProcessGroup mywebsite
    WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/vhosts/mywebsite/path/to/django/configs/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

Then restart apache

Once that is done, make sure to give your directories to the user and group www-data
as sudo (-R for recursive)

```
$ sudo chown -R deploy:www-data /path/to/webroot
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a total beginner.
On a fresh install I had to set the permissions for the /var/www/html directory.
By default they were -rw-------
I typed sudo chmod 775 * and it fuctionned.